# wordpress update postmeta using ajax is not working

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to update post meta , when a form submitted  in wordpress using jquery . So for that i write following

In my page template i write the following function after **get_footer();**

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $( "#submit_prce" ).submit(function(e) {
            var ajaxurl="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/functions.php';?>";
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = {
             action: 'update_price',
             whatever: $("#price").val()
           };
             jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
              alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
              e.preventDefault();
            });

        }); 

}); 


</script>
```

i write the following function in functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_update_price', 'update_pp_price');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_update_price', 'update_pp_price');

function update_pp_price($given_price){
    update_post_meta( 376, '_regular_price', $given_price );
    update_post_meta( 376, '_price', $given_price );
}
```

But some reason it's not working . Its showing the following error

Got this from the server:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function add_filter() in <b>/home/myshop/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme-child/functions.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
```

Comment: could you please share what is on line 14 on function.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL Wrong you should use below code.adjust ajaxurl to point admin-ajax.php

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $( "#submit_prce" ).submit(function(e) {
            var ajaxurl="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = {
             action: 'update_price',
             whatever: $("#price").val()
           };
             jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
              alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
              e.preventDefault();
            });

        }); 

}); 


</script>
```

Comment: are you sure friend ?. that means this is a silly mistake

Comment: Yes. You should use admin-ajax instead of file name.